# Binding with when injected into any condition

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a service interface

```
interface IService { }
```

and a number of implementations

```
class ServiceA : IService { }
class ServiceB : IService { }
class ServiceDefault : IService { }
```

And I have classes consuming `IService`, like

```
class ServiceUse
{
    public ServiceUse(IService svc) { }
}
```

One of the `IService` implementations should be injected into consuming class based on the context state.

To achieve this, I have `ServiceProvider` class

```
static class ServiceNames
{
    public const string ServiceA = "ServiceA";
    public const string ServiceB = "ServiceB";
    public const string ServiceDefault = "ServiceDefault";
}

class ServiceProvider : Provider<IService>
{
    protected override IService CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        ServiceKindEnum kind = GetServiceKind(HttpContext.Current);
        string bindingName = $"Service{kind}";

        if (context.Kernel.CanResolve<IService>(bindingName))
            return context.Kernel.Get<IService>(bindingName);

        return context.Kernel.Get<IService>(ServiceNames.ServiceDefault);
    }
    ...
}
```

And the bindings are

```
Bind<IService>().To<ServiceA>()
    .Named(ServiceNames.ServiceA);
Bind<IService>().To<ServiceB>()
    .Named(ServiceNames.ServiceB);
Bind<IService>().To<ServiceDefault>()
    .Named(ServiceNames.ServiceDefault);
Bind<IService>().ToProvider<ServiceProvider>()
    .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(ServiceUse));
```

Whenever another class consuming `IService` appears, such as

```
class AnotherServiceUse
{
    public AnotherServiceUse(IService svc) { }
}
```

I have to add its type as argument of `WhenInjectedInto` condition of the binding pointing to `ServiceProvider`

```
Bind<IService>().ToProvider<ServiceProvider>()
    .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(ServiceUse), typeof(AnotherServiceUse));
```

So, the list of arguments of `WhenInjectedInto` can be quite volatile during development, and this is not convenient sometimes.

I'm seeking for a way to pay less attention to `WhenInjectedInto` argument list. I feel that I need something like `WhenInjectedIntoAny` (or simply `WhenInjected`)

```
Bind<IService>().ToProvider<ServiceProvider>()
    .WhenInjected(); //target is not matter
```

What are the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code in your current questions looks now, you have two use cases for resolving `IService`:

- you're requesting a named binding - there's several services, including a named "default service".
- you're requesting an unnamed binding, which always is resolved through the same binding (the one with the provider) - which is additionally constrained with `WhenInjectedInto`.

If you're example is actually complete, the whole `WhenInjectedInto` can be heavily simplified by a condition stating that there should not be a constraint on the request. Your bindings should hence look like:

```
Bind<IService>().To<ServiceA>()
    .Named(ServiceNames.ServiceA);
Bind<IService>().To<ServiceB>()
    .Named(ServiceNames.ServiceB);
Bind<IService>().To<ServiceDefault>()
    .Named(ServiceNames.ServiceDefault);

Bind<IService>().ToProvider<ServiceProvider>()
    .When(request => request.Constraint == null);
```

In your specific example you could also give "preference" to the `ToProvider<ServiceProvider>()` binding by doing:

```
Bind<IService>().ToProvider<ServiceProvider>()
    .When(request => true);
```

This will make Ninject choose this implementation if there's multiple to choose from. Hint: this would not work if you have other bindings with conditions (`When...`) evaluating to true. To move this into an extension method add code like below:

```
public static class NinjectExtensions
{
    public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> MakePreferredBinding<T>(
        this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> syntax)
    {
        return syntax.When(req => true);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work for your scenario because requests have other Constraints than just the name, then you could employ a parameter-based solution. For interested readers, in short it works like this:

- create a custom [`IParameter`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Parameters/IParameter.cs) implementation holding a name.
- create a custom extension method for binding, based on [`When(...)`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/005e6f9e38414a38ae7c6aaf346c74ec64212609/src/Ninject/Syntax/IBindingWhenSyntax.cs#L41). This should check whether the custom parameter is on the context and whether the string matches. Apply this to all "named" service bindings instead of `Named(...)`.
- Adapt the provider to add the custom parameter (with the name) to the request intead of supplying ninject with a "name" for selection through `.Named(...)`.

Comment: @i-one if the simple solution doesn't work for you and the directions for the custom-implementation are not specific enough I'm happy to provide a complete implementation.

Comment: I found that `When(request => request.Target != null)` work in my case also, as well as `WhenInjectedInto<object>()` (this one does not seem clever, though). Could you please help me with wrapping your `When(request => request.Constraint == null)` solution into extension method, I'm lost a bit in Ninject binding syntax infrastructure. Also, do you have any thoughts regarding the difference between `request.Target != null` and `request.Constraint == null` predicates, what or when can there be a difference if one is used instead of the other?

Comment: Doing `kernel.Get<IFoo>()` `request.Target` becomes `null`. Because there's no target to inject it into. Doing `kernel.Get<IFoo>("foo")` or `kernel.Get<IFoo>(metadata => true)` makes `request.Constraint` **not** `null`.

Comment: @i-one updated the answer with an alternate solution and an extension method.